# German Visa Type D

Tags: visas, schengen, germany, long-stay-visas

I just moved recently from Lebanon to Germany for work on a visa type D. I have a business trip to France next week for 4 days and not sure whether I need to apply for a visa or fill some special documents or if I can just travel with my German visa D. Any ideas about this?
Thank you.

Comment: Do you have that visa stamped in your passport and is it still valid or do you have it as a separate card and you hold that card already?

Comment: See my comment written here: [Change of employer on type D visa while you are already in Germany - Expatriates Stack Exchange](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/questions/24363/change-of-employer-on-type-d-visa-while-you-are-already-in-germany#comment40355_24363)

Comment: @MarkJohnson if that answers the question feel free to post it here.

Comment: @JoErNanO No, it is not an answer to the question. It has more to do with getting the visa converted to a residence permit after arrival.

Answer (score 2):

If your D visa is still valid, then you are allowed to travel within the EU without needing further permission. See [below](https://www.auswaertiges-amt.de/en/visa-service/-/215870#content_1) according to the German Federal Foreign Office:

**Requirements for the issue of visas for longer stays and/or stays entitling the holder to take up gainful employment**

....As a result of Regulation 265/2010 it is now possible for anyone in possession of a national visa (D visa) and a valid travel document to move freely in the Schengen area up to three months in any six‑month period.

Comment: That should read 90 days in any 180-day period.

Comment: It was copied directly from the Foreign office site. But yes, you are correct.

Comment: Yes it does, but the original regulation quotes an older version of the Schengen Border Code that still used the **three months in any six‑month** term. It is now *90 days in any 180-day period*.

Comment: Note that travel with a D visa is **not** within the EU, its inside the Schengen Area, which is not exactly the same as the EU.